# Right align list items while keeping them on separate lines

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to align some list items in the bottom right of the webpage, with each list item's text being right aligned and the width of each list item fit to the content, so that it only activates the hover effect when it is on the actual words. However, I can't get it to achieve the effect I want.

**What I thought would fix it:** If I remove the `width: fit-content;` field from the list items, and then add `text-align: right;` it visually looks correct. However, it will activate the hover effect anywhere in the width of the list item. Also, if I try to add `float: right;` to the list items, then they are no longer on their separate lines, and rather bunch up together on the same line.

Below is some boilerplate code for the problem that I'm working with:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="selects">
        <ul>
            <li>ABOUT</li>
            <li>ME</li>
            <li>CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    html, body, .selects, .selects ul, .selects ul li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .main {
        font-size: 10vw;
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 5%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .selects {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 0;
    }

    .selects ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .selects ul li {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        /* 
        This is the field I thought would fix it.
        width: fit-content;
        */
        transition: color 0.5s;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .selects ul li:hover {
        color: #ae2e2e;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

I tried implementing the following code:

```
.selects ul li {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: fit-content; /* This */
    float: right; /* And this */
    transition: color 0.5s;
}
```

However, the "Me" and "About" list items then combined on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `li` to `width: fit-content;` and then use `flexbox` on the `ul` to position the list items correctly:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body,
.selects,
.selects ul,
.selects ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  font-size: 10vw;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.selects {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 0;
}

.selects ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* added code below */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.selects ul li {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  transition: color 0.5s;
  text-align: right;
  /* added code below */
  width: fit-content;
}

.selects ul li:hover {
  color: #ae2e2e;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="selects">
    <ul>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>ME</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```